# Scrape Patent Text in the Patent Public Search (USPTO)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to scrape patent text including title, abstract, description, and claims. The most reliable source is the Patent Public Search ([https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/](https://stackoverflow.com)), which is a dynamic website. I failed to access the content in Python.

**I don't want to use selenium** because I still need to do other work during scraping.
**I know how to scrape the Google Patents.**
**I have tried patent_client.** Patent.objects.get() returned the same error as my code. Last week patent_client worked well, but then it didn't and that's why I coded myself.

The method I know is to find the true request URL by (1) opening Inspect; (2) choosing Network; and (3) finding the request URL.
[where I find the request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOy22.jpg)
The URL I got (shown below) is the only one including the patent number (US-11235876-B2), so I guess it is what I need.
[https://ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/internal/patents/US-11235876-B2/highlight?queryId=37820229&source=USPAT&includeSections=true&uniqueId=](https://stackoverflow.com)

My code is (without import)

```
header = {'User-Agent': user, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

However, I always got either (1) 429 error, { "message": "Too many requests" }; or (2) 401 error, unauthorized. I guess the request URL I found can't be used because every time I search for a patent number, the queryId in the URL is different.

I have read the guide on external searches ([https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Patent-Public-Search-Setting-Up-External-Searches-QRG.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com)), but the query link the guide provides didn't work.